# Restrict second screen to certain window/application

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, ultramon

I have a system with two screens. On the primary screen, I want to use Windows in a normal way. On the secondary screen, I want to display a window of a certain application and nothing else. In no case should anything else than this specific window show up on the secondary screen: no other applications, no dialog boxes.

If possible, I want to restrict the mouse pointer to the primary screen as well.

I tried UltraMon, but I think my requirements go beyond its features. Any ideas?